# Capstone PCB for a single-phase power energy meter

Tags: power-electronics, single-phase, review

I am an EE major working on my capstone project of developing a PCB for a single-phase power energy meter and I need help scrutinizing it.

I Intend to interface this circuit with my Raspberry Pi 3 (connected at terminals X7-1 and X7-2). The current transformer is going to connected to terminal X6-1 and X6-2. The load for my analysis would be connected to terminals X4.

I would really appreciate any relevant comments concerning the progress of my work. Any suggestions here? Thanks.

Here is a link to the actual [Eagle file](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1FSukvpItx2aZZGsdDWWjXlnYBVw1Zwx6) for viewing.

[image]

Comment: Please name inte inputs in the schematic so one doesn't have to switch between your text and your schematic. Where does your voltage divider connect? What’s your layout situation? What’s your current sense transformer?

Comment: R34 and R10 are labelled 0R so they short-circuit your CT and you can't take any current measurements. What are the 20R and 150R resistors for on the CT input? What is a T8C5121? Datasheet link?

Comment: Also, I removed the tags that were irrelevant to the question you've asked. Also, if you need scrutinizing: Tidy up your schematic. There's plenty of angled connections that should be 90°, there's a lo of very avoidable crossings of wires, where it's not clear whether you meant to put a junction or not, you're just labelling wires "VDD" instead of using a power symbol, you're not specifying what IC4 is, and I think you *meant* switches at your TP1 to TP11. If you handed in this schematic as your project, that all would give you a solid minus on the due diligence grade.

Comment: Is V2N connected?

Comment: @winny Thanks for the feedback. The voltage divider connects at V2N(-) and V2P(+) of the divider circuit. By layout situation what do you mean please? I'm using a tape wound ring CT connected by the labels (CT+ and CT-)

Comment: @Transistor Thanks for the feedback. I used R34 and R10 as part of my filter circuit for the CT connection but I see your point. The 20R and 150R also used to serve that purpose. I used the T8C5121 because it had a similar package to that of SD3001 (a single phase energy meter IC). Here's a link to its datasheet: http://www.sdicmicro.com/DataSheet/SD3001%20Energy%20Measurement%20IC%20Datasheet%20v0.pdf

Comment: @MarcusMüller Appreciate your response too. TP1 to TP11 are test points for the divider circuit to ensure the right voltage at the various points. IC4 represents my voltage regulator, LM7805. Here's a link to its datasheet: http://ee-classes.usc.edu/ee459/library/datasheets/LM7805.pdf

Comment: Your 'LOAD' and 'GND' labels should probably be 'LOAD' and 'LINE' or 'NEUTRAL'. The datasheet link belongs in the question rather than buried in the comments. The datasheet shows that they're monitoring the voltage across a resistive shunt. You're using a CT so you need to add a shunt or 'burden' resistor.

Comment: @Transistor At which point should I include the shunt resistor please?

Comment: Across the CT input terminals as shown on the datasheet. Note that it shows L connected to the circuit ground. But your schematic still shows the 0R resistors so you still have a non-working circuit.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Yes, V2N is connected to the other end of the voltage divider circuit.

Comment: Your latest update has the shunt resistor shorting out the LOAD to NEUTRAL line. There is no LIVE connection for the 12 V PSU and the voltage divider. Back out a bit and draw a high level block diagram to clarify your thinking.

Comment: @Transistor Thanks for the notice. Viewing the schematic you placed earlier, I've made some modifications to that side of the schematic. Does this work?

Comment: Have you changed your design to scrap the CT and use a direct shunt?

Comment: @Transistor Yes, I did that. The CT readings would be taken at the ends of the shunt resistor.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with that chip and don't feel inclined to study it too deeply but offer the following observations.

[image]

*Figure 1. The SD3001 datasheet.*

Note that the shunt resistor (1) is referenced to the live input (2) which is the "ground" for the whole circuit (3) and the reference for the chip (4). That strongly suggests that the current measurement input must be correctly referenced to the chip ground. Your CT inputs aren't so you may have an issue there.

Your schematic doesn't show junctions clearly so many of the wires could be interpreted as either junctions or crossings. You should check the settings to see if you have some feature turned. off.

Turn C4 and C5 so that they are vertical which will make it clear that they are decoupling. The kink on the ground of C6 is unnecessary and similarly moving R1 up would tidy up that area. The diagonals on the TPs and the open-circuit tees add some further confusion so they should be tidied up too. They're all very small points but all add to a tidier, easier to read schematic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffIIwS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. Sample block diagram.*

Comment: @Martin: See if Figure 2 helps clarify your thinking. You should probably put a very clear label on your schematic and PCB that the low-voltage circuit is not isolated from the mains.